# App level localization in wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, localization, in-app

I need to do multi language support for my app in wp7. The user can set the language inside the app. So whenever the language is changed I need to change the strings used. How do I maintain the Resource files and have a better way of performing in app localization? There is no dependency with device display language.

Answer (score 0):

In the default localization scenario, you have a Localized class that has property for a resource file. You bind in .xaml to properties of that property. That is, for your Labels.resx files you have:

```
public class Localized
{
    private static Labels labels = new Labels();

    public Labels Labels { get { return labels; } }
}
```

The preserve your .xamls the simple change would be something like:

```
public class Localized : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ILabels Labels { ... }
}

// defines all the keys that you use in your .resx files
public interface ILabels
{
    string MainWindowHeader { get; }
    string OkLabel { get; }
    ...
}

EnglishLabels : ILabels;
GermanLabels: ILabels;
```

ILabels defines all the available texts. Upon language switch Localized sets a new value to Labels property and raises PropertyChanged.

However, I have doubts that such an app would pass certification. Why would anyone even need in-app language switch over the default behaviour?

Comment: Will you elaborate how to use ILabels? Probably in some sample codes.

Comment: @Shilpa some edits. This solution is based on the default way of windows phone localizing. If you're asking, how that is done, see for example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff637520(v=vs.105).aspx . The ChangeLanguageCommand needs just to get the reference to Localized from App ResourceDictionary.

Comment: Default way is device level localization correct? I need in app localization. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @SHILPA this is the solution for in-app localization, but it's based on the default way of localizing, because i assume, that when you're going for the non-standard way, you know already the basic one.